# Right way for observing background script output

Tags: python, django

I have a server script for file processing. It's write on Python and Django. Goal of this script is a PDF file processing when pdf drop in hot folder.

I want to check script output in real-time mode. Previously I was doing in such a way - launch console, and from my program:

```
TTY = '/dev/tty1'
sys.stdout = open(TTY, 'w')
print 'I see it in console'
```

Is there convenient way to observing script output in browser in real-time mode? I need it only for debug/testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Django Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) module:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.error('Something is happening!')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already use logging module for a logging purpose. In my question I talk about console-like output in real-time mode. For example, I want look at my progress-bar of ftp upload process.